# commons-exec CommandLine Doesn't Accept "*"?

Tags: java

I tried both CommandLine#parse and addArgument:

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

executor.execute(CommandLine.parse("ls /Users/jizhang/*.py"));

CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("ls");
cmd.addArgument("/Users/jizhang/*.py", false);
executor.execute(cmd);
```

The exception is:

```
ls: /Users/jizhang/*.py: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

But actually there are files in that folder:

```
prey:~ jizhang$ ls /Users/jizhang/*.py
/Users/jizhang/ana.py        /Users/jizhang/send_image.py
/Users/jizhang/push.py       /Users/jizhang/t.py
```

I believe it's about quotation, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: On UNIX, the shell is responsible to expand wildcards like *. If you pass it literally to a program like `ls` the result is `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to put your command line an .sh file, and then run it using sh command:

```
executor.execute(CommandLine.parse("/bin/sh /home/path_to_my_cmd.sh"));

// content of file path_to_my_cmd.sh
ls /Users/jizhang/*.py
```